# Cloning a Builder object in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following Kotlin code, which is a simplification of my problem:

```
val baseBuilder : Builder =
    Builder("xx")
        .setA("aa")
        .setB("bb")

fun f(action: Action): Builder {
    var extraBuilder = baseBuilder
        .add(action)
    return extraBuilder
}
```

If I call f many times I end up with a builder having many actions added to it, but I want f to return a builder that has only one action. I can't change the implementation of that Builder class. I thought of making a copy of the baseBuilder inside the f function but I couldn't find how. Or maybe I can achieve what I want in other way?

Comment: If you ever do need a property that is dependent on other functions that must be called each time it is accessed, you can give it a custom getter. But in cases like this, it's kind of an anti-pattern to use a property for it since it doesn't fit the idea of what a property is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `baseBuilder` a function, not a value.

```
fun baseBuilder() = Builder("xx").setA("aa").setB("bb")

fun f(action: Action): Builder) {
  return baseBuilder().add(action)
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So simple.. I think I'm too tired xd

Comment: And within a minute of each other. Have an upvote, both of you :P

Answer (score 4):

The builder is simple setup, nothing heavy, so just change `baseBuilder` to be a method, so every call creates and new builder.

```kotlin
fun baseBuilder() : Builder {
    return Builder("xx")
        .setA("aa")
        .setB("bb")
}

fun f(action: Action): Builder {
    var extraBuilder = baseBuilder()
        .add(action)
    return extraBuilder
}
```

Comment: Gotta give it to the first ;p